# Microsoft Surface Pro - Extend to 2 monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I'm finding it difficult to use my laptop for the programs I'm currently using.  I have 2 separate monitors and what I'd like to do is extend to those 2 outputs.  I've managed to do this with the VGA cables and a VGA splitter but unfortunately it's treating the 2 monitors as one and I can't extend the display.  Is there anyway round this if say I switch to HDMI cables? Many thanks.

Comment: Does your device even support HDMI?  Based on my personal experience Surface devices typically only support Display Port.

Comment: I have a colleague from a while back who did just this. He had a Dock for the Surface and the Monitors (and Keyboard / Mouse) were attached to the Dock. It worked fine. I suggest the dock to you as well

Answer (score 0):

A splitter does just that : splits one stream into two identical streams.

As the Surface has only one display port, and you need two,
you need to get a dock that that will give you one more display port.